# Non-blocking C++ sockets

Tags: c++, asynchronous, socket

I'm trying to use sockets to create a simple client and server architecture and I'm wondering if there is any other way to create non-blocking, 'async' sockets instead using `fcntl()`, `select()` or Boost Library? How can I implement this in a C++ style? I'm using threads to accept new connections and receive data, but in this case it doesn't work well enough (receive hangs, waiting for data, vector isn't a good container for thread based operations etc.).

My code:

```
const char * SERVER_HOST = "127.0.0.1";
const unsigned short MAX_CONNECTIONS = 10;
const int MAX_DATA_BUFFER = 4096;
const unsigned int SERVER_PORT = 8989;

std::vector<int> clients;

int acceptClient(int serverFd, sockaddr* saddr, socklen_t *sin_size)
{
    while(true)
    {
        int newSocketFd = accept(serverFd, saddr, sin_size);

        if (newSocketFd != -1)
        {
            clients.push_back(newSocketFd);
            std::cout << "New client!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int recive()
{
    while(true)
    {
        for(auto x : clients)
        {
            char buffer[4096];
            int nbytes = recv(x, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
            std::cout << "Socket descriptor: " << x << std::endl;
            if (nbytes != -1)
            {
                buffer[nbytes] = '\0';
                string str(buffer);
                std::cout << "Recived from: " << x << " " << str << std::endl;
            }

            if (nbytes == 0)
            {
                std::cout << "Connection refused..." << std::endl;
                std::remove_if(clients.begin(), clients.end(), [x](int fd)->bool{fd = x;});
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int serverFd;
    struct sockaddr_in serverSockAddr = {};
    serverSockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serverSockAddr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
    serverSockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    memset(&serverSockAddr.sin_zero, '\0', 8);

    if ((serverFd= socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    std::cout << "Socket created..." << std::endl;

    if (bind(serverFd, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr * >(&serverSockAddr), sizeof(sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
        perror("bind");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    std::cout << "Bind complete..." << std::endl;

    int yes = 1;
    if (setsockopt(serverFd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1)
    {
        perror("setsockpt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    std::cout << "Socket cleared if stuck..." << std::endl;

    if (listen(serverFd, MAX_CONNECTIONS) == -1)
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    std::cout << "Socket listen..." << std::endl;

    int clientFd;
    socklen_t sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    sockaddr_in clientSockAddr = {};

    std::thread t1 (acceptClient, serverFd, reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr*>(&clientSockAddr), &sin_size);
    std::thread t2 (recive);

    char buf[1024];
    std::cin>>buf;

    return 0;
```

Comment: I would use [`libEvent`](http://libevent.org/) that will tell you when a socket has data and you can go get it. But that is very low level. Above that there is boost async io [`boost.asio`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) library that virtualize sockets into sinks and streams. There is nothing really in between (that I know of).

Comment: PS. Using threads to increase parallelism to read more from sockets is the wrong way to go. Socket communication is inherently slow (compared to processors) and threads are expensive and bulky. The better way to go is have a single thread  multiplex across thousands of connections. This is how modern web servers work.  See [C10K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem).

Comment: If you are interested I have wrapped sockets. To provide a non blocking `std::istream`. So you can create a socket connection and it behaves like a normal `std::istream`. Any blocking operation causes the thread to finds another stream to handle. See [ThorsNissa](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsNisse). It is noware as polished or advanced as boost asio but I work on it when I have time. Current documentation here: http://lokiastari.com/ThorsNisse/#introduction

Comment: 'it doesn't work well enough' suggests you are asking about improving broken / unfinished code. If so, this question is off-topic here.

Comment: @MartinYork Meta discussion [here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8874/answering-questions-in-comments).